# How to return textcontent from tags in DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, innerhtml

I have the following code:

```
    <table>
    <tbody style="font-size: 50px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color: #ffffff;">Q</td>
            <td style="color: #442244; background-color: #442244;">Y</td>
            <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #442244;">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: #ffeefe; background-color: #990000;">Q</td>
            <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #ffff00;">M</td>
            <td style="color: #000000; background-color: #ff7777;">O</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have to write function in Javasript which return all letters in array. Then I have to return all letters where 
color == background-color

Comment: best is,
select all the `tr` from selected table then loop through them with  `if` condition which will compare **color** and store all the characters using `innerHTML` or `textContent` in an array then do your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Below code returns all letters from your submitted html.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("td")).map(cell => cell.innerText)
```

2. Below code returns all letters where their td color and bg-color values are equal.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("td")).filter(cell => cell.style.color && cell.style.backgroundColor && cell.style.color === cell.style.backgroundColor).map(cell => cell.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of `tds` using `document.getElementByTagName`, then `reduce` those elements into the letters depending if the color == backgroundColor:

```js
const letters = [...document.getElementsByTagName('td')].reduce((a, el) => (
  el.style.color === el.style.backgroundColor && a.push(el.textContent), a
), [])

console.log(letters)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody style="font-size: 50px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color: #ffffff;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #442244; background-color: #442244;">Y</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #442244;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ffeefe; background-color: #990000;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #ffff00;">M</td>
      <td style="color: #000000; background-color: #ff7777;">O</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

this function bellow can do what you need:

```js
function getLetters() {
   const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("td"));
   return tds.filter(td => td.style.color === td.style.backgroundColor)
      .map(td => td.textContent);
}

const letters = getLetters();

console.log(letters)
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody style="font-size: 50px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color: #ffffff;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #442244; background-color: #442244;">Y</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #442244;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ffeefe; background-color: #990000;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #ffff00;">M</td>
      <td style="color: #000000; background-color: #ff7777;">O</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const hexToRgb = hex => 'rgb(' + hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/g).map(c => parseInt(c, 16)).join(', ') + ')';

let charsWithBackgroundColor = backgroundColor => 
  [...document.querySelectorAll('td')]
    .filter(td => td.style.backgroundColor === hexToRgb(backgroundColor))
    .map(td => td.textContent);

console.log(charsWithBackgroundColor('#442244')); // ['Y', 'A']
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody style="font-size: 50px;">
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color: #ffffff;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #442244; background-color: #442244;">Y</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #442244;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ffeefe; background-color: #990000;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #ffff00; background-color: #ffff00;">M</td>
      <td style="color: #000000; background-color: #ff7777;">O</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking for elements of a specific background color, in this case, `#442244`

Comment: OP said where its color == background color.

Comment: I interpreted `color` as a parameter to a function. No point in editing the answer now, since the other answers already cover the the other interpretation.